# Parcelable and Inheritance

Tags: android, inheritance, bundle, multiple-inheritance, parcelable

This has been asked a few times here on SO, but my case is a bit different.

I have class A that implements Parcelable.  Class A contains some member data that can be parceled. It has its own `CREATOR` and implements `writeToParcel()`, `describeContents()`, and a constructor that accepts a `Parcel`.

There is class B that extends from class A.  Class B has additional member data, but **none of them need to be parceled**. Basically, class B's parcelable data is the same as class A. If I try to put B in a Bundle, pass it to another Activity, and read it back, I would get a ClassCastException. I guess that's expected.

After a bit of trial-and-error, in order to make class B parcelable, I have to implement at least these two things:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<B> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<B>() {
    public B createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new B(source);
    }

    public B[] newArray(int size) {
        return new B[size];
    }
};

public B(Parcel in) throws JSONException {
    super(in);
}
```

So my concern is this.  There are about half a dozen or more classes that extend from A and all have the same issue as B. It seems silly that each one of them has to add their own static `CREATOR` and a constructor that accepts a `Parcel`, only to pass it back to A. Everything else is identical.  The only thing that makes it different is the name of the class. It beats the purpose of having inheritance in the first place.

For example, if there's another class C that extends B, I need to do the same:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<C> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<C>() {
    public C createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new C(source);
    }

    public C[] newArray(int size) {
        return new C[size];
    }
};

public C(Parcel in) throws JSONException {
    super(in);
}
```

Is there some sort of clever techniques in Java to automate this process?  Perhaps using generic of some sort? If there's no other way, I might just as well just remove the inheritance lineage, and require each class to implement Parcelable themselves.

Comment: I'm a little late but here is how I handled this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20018463/362298

Answer (score 2):

This is a little complicated, but the only way I can think of offhand involves reflection - Provided all of the subclasses have a constructor that takes a `Parcel` that then calls `super(parcel)`, you could make the class name a part of the parcel - then in your createFromParcel method of A:

```
public A createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
    Class clazz = Class.forName(source.readString());
    Class[1] paramTypes = { Parcel.class }; 
    Constructor ctor = clazz.getConstructor(paramTypes);
    A myA = (A) ctor.newInstance(source);
    return myA;
}
```

Note that this was written largely off the cuff and may need some tweaking before it runs (I know for sure it's missing checked exception handlers) - but hopefully the idea is clear

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented the solution described by JRaymond and it works.  It's a little complicated since it involves some reflection,but i hope it helps someone else. Now any class that is parcelable should extend this GlobalParcelable class which implements parcelable.

https://github.com/awadalaa/Android-Global-Parcelable